# In Linux programming, how do I share data between two unrelated user processes?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, shared-memory

I've been given a task to write a Linux shared library that two or more processes can use to share data between them. I'm puzzled at how I could share data between unrelated processes as they don't share file handles, memory space or anything else. Does anyone have ideas how two or more processes could share data between them through the same library?

I need to write an API for the library also. I came up with API but I don't know how to implement it completely.

The API looks like this:

```
library.registerProcess(name) - registers process in library
library.createSharedData(size) - creates shared data of size (in bytes)
library.getSharedData(name) - get shared data of process by name
```

Now process1 can call `library.registerProcess('process1')`. Then process2 can call `library.registerProcess('process2')`.

Now process1 can call `library.createSharedData('1mb')` to create a shared data region of 1mb in size.

Process2 can now call `library.getSharedData('process1')` which returns `process1` shared data (some object or structure that maybe contains pointer to memory that can be accessed).

I'm really puzzled at how two unrelated processed could talk and use this API.

Comment: The general term is "interprocess communication" sometimes abbreviated as "IPC". And there are several ways to go about it.

Comment: Standard posix ipc include: pipes, domain sockets, fifos, msg queues, shared memory.  From the looks of your API it looks like you want to use shared memory so you should read up on that and that and interprocess semaphores to protect the data so one process doesn't step on the work of the other.

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ; you also need some synchronization in your API